# Using Nested For Loops and an Array in MIPS

Tags: c, arrays, assembly, mips

This is a homework assignment, I've written the whole program myself, run through it in the debugger, and everything plays out the way I mean it to EXCEPT for this line:

`sw $t1, counter($a3)`

The assignment is to convert this snippet of C code to MIPS

```
    for(i = 0; i < a; i++) {
       for(j = 0; j < b; j++) {
          C[2 * i] = i – j; } }
```

All the registers change values the way they should in my program except for $a3 - It never changes.

Changes: An array needed to be declared and "pointed to" by a register and a label can't be used for an offset in the manner I started with

EDIT: Here's the finished, working code

[image: Finished]

Comment: Why did you expect $a3 to change ? It should be the address of your array, and thus it should not change. Actually I don't understand what is your problem.

Comment: @ElderBug I'm *trying* to store the result of i - j in each index of $a3, so shouldn't I be seeing some value popping up in the $a3 register value space? I'm not sure how better to explain myself, would a screenshot of my mars compiler help? I can show you what I'm looking at

Comment: If you have the line `sw $t1, x($a3)` with x=8, the value of t1 will be stored at $a3[2] (3rd int of your array, pointed by $a3). If it is not the case, then the line is never executed.

Comment: Okay, that's good, that's what I want it to do. How do I declare an array and make $a3 point to it?

Comment: I'm not sure about the MIPS syntax, but to declare it should be like `myarray: .space 40` for 10 words. Then you have to load the address into $a3, with `la $a3, myarray`, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Okay, awesome, I surprised myself figuring that one out before you responded! But now I'm crashing with this error line: Assignment2.asm line 30: Runtime exception at 0x00400064: address out of range 0x20020100     Also see my question, posted a screencap

Comment: Your loops are wrong. Currently you will loop until `i==a`, instead of stopping after `a-1`. Also, your construct is a bit awkward. Remember that `for(i=0;i<a;i++){loop;}` is translated to `i=0;while(i<a){loop;i++}`, and this can be directly translated into assembly.

Comment: Lines 12 and 13 make it a- 1. And I don't know how to do that, never really worked with assembly

Comment: Actually, you are right on this point, I forgot that you use `i-1` later. Anyway, your loops are still wrong. Try to translate the `while`, that's really straightforward. Just translate what the `while` do step by step. The only not direct point is that the condition is a "continue" condition, when you need an "exit" condition (but that's just the opposite). And translate one loop at a time, it doesn't even matter if you have duplicate labels.

Comment: Not even going to argue, looked at our lecture slides and reformatted the loops and it works perfectly now, didn't even realize the for loops weren't functioning right at the time. Why does changing the loop structure fix the address out of bounds issue? And ONE LAST QUESTION: When I look at the location of the array in the register, it starts with an offset of 8, but I looked in the debugger and it isn't being given an offset, why wouldn't it start at 0?

Comment: Did you change the code in your question to correct the problem? **Please** don't do that. By not showing the problematic code in the question, you can make it useless.

Comment: @KeithThompson just added the revision, didn't remove anything important to the initial problem itself

Comment: Still, if that's the "finished, working code" it belongs in an answer, not in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Recap answer from the comments**

Your $a3 register, is supposed to be loaded with the address of an array defined in the `.data` section.

One big problem with your code is how you constructed your loops. The best way is to translate your loops step by step, and one loop at a time. Also, remember that :

```
for( i = 0; i < a; i++ )
{
    loop_content;
}
```

Is equivalent to :

```
i = 0;
while( i < a )
{
    loop_content;
    i++;
}
```

Which is easier to translate in assembly. The condition just have to be negated, has you need an "exit" condition, and not a "continue" condition as in a `while` loop. Your code will be much clearer and easier to understand (and less error prone).

Your "out of range" error comes from here : `sw $t1, counter($a3)`. Here `counter` is a label, and therefore an address. Thus `counter($a3)` is doing "$a3 (=0x10010008) + address of counter (=0x100100f8)", giving 0x20020100, which is clearly not what you want (and non-sense).

Oh, and in the `sw $r, offset($a)` MIPS instruction, `offset` MUST be a 16-bit CONSTANT. Here, you use a 32-bit address, but it's just that the assembler kindly translate `sw $t1, counter($a3)` to `$x = $a3 + counter; sw $t1, 0($x)`, which is why you may see a `sw` with 0 as offset.

Comment: You're the man, that makes sense and I have a much better understanding of what is happening. Will post revised, polished code later for reference, let me know if there is anything I can do to make it more efficient or "cleaner". Thanks again